# How can I get values from a function on Fortran?

Tags: function, fortran, character, fortran90, character-arrays

This is a simple program that performs a base conversion.
I try to print out the values using a loop and the directive:

```
write (*,'(i4,a,a)') it," = ",baseConversion(it,base)
```

For some reason I can't get the values using this line

```
program echeverria_4

implicit none 

interface
    function baseConversion(anumber,abase)
    character(8) :: baseConversion
    integer,intent(in) :: anumber, abase 
    end function baseConversion
end interface

    integer :: firstNumbers,base,it, numero
    character(8),dimension(100) :: rangeNumbers

    !Part A
    write(*,*) "Project 4 Part A"
    firstNumbers = 20
    base = 11

    write(*,'(i4,i4)') firstNumbers, base   

    do it = 1, firstNumbers
        write (*,'(i4,a,a)') it," = ",baseConversion(it,base)
    end do 

end program echeverria_4


function trans(anumber)
implicit none 
    character :: trans
    integer,intent(in):: anumber 

    integer :: conversor1 = 48
    integer :: conversor2 = 55
    if (anumber >= 10) then 
        trans = char(anumber+conversor2)
    else
        trans = char(anumber+conversor1)
    endif
end function trans


function baseConversion(anumber, abase)

    implicit none

    interface
        function trans(anumber)
            character :: trans
            integer,intent(in):: anumber
        end function trans
    end interface

        character(8):: baseConversion
        integer,intent(in):: anumber,abase

        character(8) :: leftmost
        logical :: is_process_complete = .false.
        integer :: remainder,division,localNumber

        localNumber = anumber

        do while(.not. is_process_complete) 
            !Step 1: Find the remainder
            remainder = mod(localNumber,abase)
            !Step 2: Divide the number by the base 
            division = localNumber/abase
            if (division>0) then 
                localNumber = division
                leftmost=trans(remainder)//leftmost
            else
                is_process_complete=.true.
                leftmost=trans(remainder)//leftmost
            end if
        end do

        write(baseConversion,'(a)') leftmost
end function baseConversion
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easier if you place your procedures (subroutines and functions) into modules and then `use` the  module for any program or procedure that needs those procedures.  This automatically makes the interfaces explicit. You don't have to write interfaces ... less work, less chance of mistakes.  So:

```
module MyModule

contains


function trans(anumber)
implicit none
    character :: trans
    integer,intent(in):: anumber

    integer :: conversor1 = 48
    integer :: conversor2 = 55
    if (anumber >= 10) then
        trans = char(anumber+conversor2)
    else
        trans = char(anumber+conversor1)
    endif
end function trans


function baseConversion(anumber, abase)

    implicit none

        character(8):: baseConversion
        integer,intent(in):: anumber,abase

        character(8) :: leftmost
        logical :: is_process_complete = .false.
        integer :: remainder,division,localNumber

        localNumber = anumber

        do while(.not. is_process_complete)
            !Step 1: Find the remainder
            remainder = mod(localNumber,abase)
            !Step 2: Divide the number by the base
            division = localNumber/abase
            if (division>0) then
                localNumber = division
                leftmost=trans(remainder)//leftmost
            else
                is_process_complete=.true.
                leftmost=trans(remainder)//leftmost
            end if
        end do

        write(baseConversion,'(a)') leftmost
end function baseConversion

end module MyModule


program echeverria_4

use MyModule

implicit none

    integer :: firstNumbers,base,it, numero
    character(8),dimension(100) :: rangeNumbers

    !Part A
    write(*,*) "Project 4 Part A"
    firstNumbers = 20
    base = 11

    write(*,'(i4,i4)') firstNumbers, base

    do it = 1, firstNumbers
        write (*,'(i4,a,a)') it," = ",baseConversion(it,base)
    end do

end program echeverria_4
```

When I compile this with gfortran with extensive error/warning options, I get the following warning messages:

```
test99.f90:42.51:

                leftmost=trans(remainder)//leftmost
                                                   1
Warning: CHARACTER expression will be truncated in assignment (8/9) at (1)
test99.f90:45.51:

                leftmost=trans(remainder)//leftmost
                                                   1
Warning: CHARACTER expression will be truncated in assignment (8/9) at (1)
```

Fixing those might make your program work.  It is at least a first step.